# Break outside loop Python function other options

Tags: python, function, break

I have some code:

```
def playAgain1():
    print("Would you like to keep boxing or quit while you are ahead? (y/n)")
    playAgain = input().lower()
    if(playAgain.startswith('y') == False):
        print("Whatever you chicken.")
        break
```

I want it to break the loop if `playAgain()` doesn't start with `y`. Whenever I try, I get the error:

> 'break' outside loop

How could I write this better to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt Bryant's answer states, you can't break outside a loop but can just return from the function. I would add that you probably need to return a value from your function, so that the main programme loop knows whether to return to the start or quit:

```
def main():
    while True:
        # main game code goes here
        if not playAgain():
            break

def playAgain():
    print("Would you like to keep boxing or quit while you are ahead? (y/n)")
    response = input().lower()
    return response.startswith('y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `break` with `return`.  `break` can only be used inside a loop, while `return` works anywhere in a function.  The final code would look like this:

```
def playAgain1():
    print("Would you like to keep boxing or quit while you are ahead? (y/n)")
    playAgain = input().lower()
    if not playAgain.startswith('y'):
        print("Whatever you chicken.")
        return
    else:
        # do whatever you do when they say yes
```